# Custom item list view with Image View after the last character of textview

Tags: android, listview

I want custom item list view same image
[image]

what can i do to create item list view with small image view just like in the picture
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you actually want the image to be inline with the text.

In this case, you wouldn't use an `ImageView`.  You would create a `Spannable` that contains an `ImageSpan` and assign it to the `TextView`.

```
        String str = "Thank you very much [icon]";
        int start = str.indexOf("[icon]");
        int end = start + "[icon]".length();
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(str); 
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.headphones); 
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d); 
        ss.setSpan(span, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
        textView.setText(ss);
```

Comment: yes, it is true, but when I try resize imagespan and add in Spannable it does not line up with text, Can you help me?

Comment: How do you want it to line up with the text? Can you post the code you're using and a picture of the result with a description of how it should be lined up?

Answer (score 0):

Use a textView, create html text with image tag, use `Html.fromHtml`. Read the docs on fromHtml, as you will still have to replace the images.
Alternatively, you can use a WebView, though I don't like the overhead.

Comment: fromHtml also creates a Scannable. I just think it may be easier, though kris's idea gives you more control.